# How to check if the library module need to re-compile with gradle in android?

Tags: android, gradle

My android project consists of three library module. Each time I build the project with gradle, it will build the library module which it hasn't changed. My Question is how to check if the library module is up-to-date when build , so the build will skip it to improve build time .

Comment: That check happens automatically. When running with `--info`, Gradle will tell you why it thinks that a task is out of date.

Comment: I have a build script and i want to know how to check if each module need to update with code, so the script will skip compiling specify module?

Comment: As I said, this is automatic. First thing to do is to understand *why* the tasks are out of date, which you can do by checking the `--info` log.